# Surjectivity of Lang map

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, algebraic-groups

Could we prove the surjectivity of Lang's map for $GL(N)$ without using algebraic geometry?

In other words, given a invertible matrix $M$ in $GL_N(\mathbb{F})$, there exists another invertible matrix $P$ in $GL_N(\mathbb{F})$ such that $P^{-1}P^{(q)}=M$.

Here $\mathbb{F}$ denotes as an algebraically closed field $\mathbb{F}_p$.  And $P^{(q)}$ is the coordinate-wise $q$-power where $q$ is a fixed power of $p$.

Comment: It is easy to show that there is a solution $P$, if $M$ is in Jordan canonical form (available now that we work over an algebraically closed field). Unfortunately that doesn't settle the question. For a similarity transformation doesn't mesh well with the $\strut^{(q)}$-operation. So my first idea failed :-(

Comment: Just interested if you finally got an answer